# How To change input type value based on select dropdown box in Laravel with if statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a vehicle rental & service web site. So, I want to create a repair booking form in this web site. There are drop down box which have vehicle type and text field which have price in this form. Now I want to show relevant price in same page when someone change the vehicle type from the drop down box. I am very new to laravel.
How can I do this ??

Here is my Form.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l2">
<input type="text" style="color: black" value="{{config('app.currency').$repair_type->finalPrice }}" class="form-btn" disabled>
</div>
                                
                        
<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l2">

<select name="vehicletype" id="vehicletype" >
<option value="regularsizecar"
 @if (Input::old('vehicletype') == 'regularsizecar') selected="selected" @endif>Regular Size Car
                                            
 </option>
 <option value="mediumsizecar"
 @if (Input::old('vehicletype') == 'mediumsizecar') selected="selected" @endif>Medium Size Car
                                             
 </option>
 <option value="compactsuv"
  @if (Input::old('vehicletype') == 'compactsuv') selected="selected" @endif>Compact SUV
                                             
 </option>
 <option value="minivan"
  @if (Input::old('vehicletype') == 'minivan') selected="selected" @endif>Mini Van
                                              
 </option>
                                            
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're trying to do needs either "the form to be submitted if you are set on using PHP/Laravel" or "you need to use Javascript to listen for change to select option and then do what you plan on doing based on selection (either static values or AJAX)".

Comment: I planned, If user select vehicle type, the price value should be change accordingly.(static values)